# Can Range.Value2 & Range.Formula have different values in C#, not VBA?

Tags: c#, excel, range, com-interop, formula

I want to create a `UDF` which is like `GetPath(parameter)`, where parameter can be a cell reference like `"B1"`, or a string 
what the `GetPath` does, based on input, it will call web service to get path for input 
e.g. formula of cell `A1=GetPath(B1)`,  cell `B1` has some string,  the function should return path and put it in cell A1, i.e. `"Value2"` of A1 should be path of B1.

Now in C#, when I did sth `FormulaCell.Value2 = path`, its formula changes, too
but I want "Formula" & "Value2" to be different.

I know this is possible in VBA, but I am using C#.

Anyone knows how to accomplish this?

thanks

I googled, googled and still not found a solution. 
This sounds like a basic feature but impossible in C#. at least that's what I got through research. I am sure some of you have encountered the same issue before, just wonder how you work it out?

I am going to try this in VB.NET if that works then I will reference it in C#. If anyone knows in VB.NET, pls also post. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My addin was COM AddIn which is not possible to have range.value2 different from range.formula
no matter it is C# or VB.NET.

This can be done using VBA, Automation AddIn in .NET, or xll addin. 
For xll addin, you can either write in C/C++, or use existing tools like ExcelDNA, managedXLL, XLW, etc.